# Error Parsing JSON file in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am developing an Android application which fetches data from a server through `HTTP GET`, stores the response (`JSON` format) in a String. I want to parse the String and get the values within the `JSONArray`.

The received JSON which is stored in the STRING is :

```
{"code":1,"data":{"survey":{"id":null,"questionAnswers":[{"id":null,"min":"1","max":"5","step":"0.1","last":"4.7","text":"I am happy at work today","key":"Mood","testQuestionId":"1","datetime":"2014-04-29 15:47:02","answer":"4.7","testAnswerId":null}]}}
```

I want to parse the JSON Array `"questionAnswers"`, and retrieve the value in `"answer"`, which is inside a `JSONObject`.

The code I used is as follows :

```
                JSONObject jsonObj_survey = new JSONObject(Get_MySurvey_JSON);
    JSONObject jsondata_survey = jsonObj_survey.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray jsonArray_questionAnswer = jsondata_survey
            .getJSONArray("questionAnswers");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_questionAnswer.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject questionAnswer = jsonArray_questionAnswer
                .getJSONObject(i);

        my_Company_survey_rating[i] = questionAnswer.getString("answer");
        // userdata.setMy_Company_Top_key_1(my_Company_Top_key[1]);

        Log.d("Rating", my_Company_survey_rating[i]);
    }
```

I am unable to parse it and obtaining an exception :

```
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189): org.json.JSONException: No value for questionAnswers
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at com.moodwonder.fi.HTTP_SignIn_Thread.doInBackground(HTTP_SignIn_Thread.java:224)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at com.moodwonder.fi.HTTP_SignIn_Thread.doInBackground(HTTP_SignIn_Thread.java:1)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-29 18:28:00.272: W/System.err(13189):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: put your json here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ it's display invalid json

Comment: your curly braces in the JSON don't match. You got 4 open braces and only 3 closing. Can you try fixing that and re-try your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338695/json-parsed-data-not-shwoing-in-list/23339245#23339245

You can refer same code for parsing json to object ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are trying to get JSONArray of **"questionAnswers"** from
>   **"data"** instead of **"survey"**

```
String yourJSONString = "{"code":1,"data":{"survey":{"id":null,"questionAnswers":[{"id":null,"min":"1","max":"5","step":"0.1","last":"4.7","text":"I am happy at work today","key":"Mood","testQuestionId":"1","datetime":"2014-04-29 15:47:02","answer":"4.7","testAnswerId":null}]}}}";

JSONObject jObj_main = new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
JSONObject jOb_data = jObj_main.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject jOb_survey = jOb_data.getJSONObject("survey");
JSONArray jArray_questionAnswers = jOb_survey.getJSONArray("questionAnswers");
```

Comment: Thanks Archie. It worked. The file which I received from the server was also partially empty. Still the fix works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
  JSONObject jsonObj_survey = new JSONObject(Get_MySurvey_JSON);
                JSONObject jsondata_survey = jsonObj_survey.getJSONObject("data");

                JSONObject jsondata_surveyvalue = jsonObj_survey.getJSONObject("survey");
                JSONArray jsonArray_questionAnswer = jsondata_surveyvalue
                        .getJSONArray("questionAnswers");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_questionAnswer.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject questionAnswer = jsonArray_questionAnswer
                            .getJSONObject(i);

                    my_Company_survey_rating[i] = questionAnswer.getString("answer");
                    // userdata.setMy_Company_Top_key_1(my_Company_Top_key[1]);

                    Log.d("Rating", my_Company_survey_rating[i]);

                           }
```

Hope this code helps you!!
is it is not working please let me know i will try to help more.